# Редактирование отступа в проводнике VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Подскажите, как увеличить отступ файлов в проводнике VS Code? Иконка файла визуально почти на уровне стрелочки родительской директории, не очень удобно, что строки сливаются

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Установить любую тему значков с отображением значков папок и стрелочек. И все станет удобно. Например Matherial Icon Theme

Answer (score 2):

В раздел Settings(JSON) добавить поле "workbench.tree.indent": [отступ].
Например "workbench.tree.indent": 16

Settings(JSON) можно найти в поиске (F1) ввести ">Open Settings (json)"

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Файл - Настройки - Параметры - найти: tree indent - поменять значение.

[image: Файл - Настройки - Параметры - найти: tree indent - поменять значение]